# How can I keep track of clicks on a specific subset of elements on a page to track each items popularity?

Tags: javascript, analytics, tracking

I have a site where I have a bunch of boxes arranged in a grid that each link to an article. I'd like to track the popularity of each 'box' somehow. I'd like to then have a button that allows for the user to sort these boxes by popularity.

Is there some sort of basic free analytics suite that allows for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this plugin](https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/) can help you

it allow you to sort by field you want with attributes on tags
example:

```
  <figure class="col-4@sm picture-item" data-groups='["photography"]' data-date-created="2010-09-14" data-title="Baseball">
    <div class="aspect aspect--16x9">
      <div class="aspect__inner">
        <img src="/img/baseball.png" alt="" height="145" width="230">
      </div>
    </div>
    <figcaption>Baseball</figcaption>
  </figure>
```

here is data-title attribute for example you can change it to popularity

Comment: Thanks for that script but I meant more something that I can use to collect data on clicks to specific page elements not a shuffle script. I'm looking for a way to gather the popularity.